# Download file from Firebase Storage using Alamofire in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, alamofire

I'm very new in iOS development. So I'm trying to download pdf or image from firebase storage with URL using Alamofire and then I want to display with quicklook. I tried this example but no luck. [Present preview of downloaded file directly in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54125804/present-preview-of-downloaded-file-directly-in-app)

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import QuickLook

class DocumentViewer: UIViewController{
    var previewItem = URL?.self
    var refrenceDocURL: URL? // here i get the url from another view controller but never use it because I don't know where should I use it.
    
    func downloadFile(fileUrl: URL) {
        let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in //ERROR: 'DownloadFileDestination' is not a member type of class 'Alamofire.DownloadRequest'
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(documentFilename)
            return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile])
        }

        Alamofire.download(fileUrl, to: destination)   //ERROR: Module 'Alamofire' has no member named 'download'
            .response(completionHandler: { (downloadResponse) in

              let previewController = QLPreviewController()
              previewController.dataSource = self
              self.previewItem = downloadResponse.destinationURL
              self.present(previewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
          })
        }
      }

extension DocumentViewer: QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
    func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
       return self.previewItem as! QLPreviewItem
    }
}
```

[image: Here is a screen shoot of the error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using old definitions.

`DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination` is `DownloadRequest.Destination`.

`Alamofire.download` is `AF.download`.

Comment: I just installed the Alamofire and the verison = 5.6.1

Comment: Ah, then the problem is the inverse: you're using old type definitions. I've updated the answer.